# How to update cell containing a list using values from a pd.Series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the folowing dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'cols': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'vals': [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]})
series = pd.Series([3,5])
df
OUT:
    cols    vals
0   a   [1, 2]
1   b   [3, 4]
2   c   [5, 6]

series
OUT:
0    3
1    5
```

i would like to get the following result:

```
cols    vals
0   a   [1, 2, 3]
1   b   [3, 4, 5]
2   c   [5, 6]
```

How can i achieve this without using itterrows?

Comment: there is no `7` ?

Comment: yes, there is no 7. I want to update only for common indexes

Comment: so `series = pd.Series([3,5,7])` is wrong?

Comment: sorry, i haven't noticed. I just edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

good old `+=` with index alignment:

```
df.loc[series.index, 'vals'] += pd.Series([[i] for i in series], index=series.index)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a list comprehension and slice assign back to `vals` (this assumes the index is a normal `range`):

```
df.loc[:len(series)-1, 'vals'] = [i+[j] for i,j in zip(df.loc[:len(series)-1, 'vals'], series)]

print(df)

   cols       vals
0    a  [1, 2, 3]
1    b  [3, 4, 5]
2    c     [5, 6]
```

Answer (score 3):

Altenatively with [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html)

```
df['vals'] = df['vals'].explode().append(series).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
print(df)
```

---

```
  cols       vals
0    a  [1, 2, 3]
1    b  [3, 4, 5]
2    c     [5, 6]
```

Comment: This, similar to my answer, might give extra if `series` has index not in `df.index`, but is easier to fix.

Comment: @QuangHoang you are correct , chaining a reindex or `.loc[df.index]` should fix it then: `df['vals'].explode().append(series).groupby(level=0).agg(list).loc[df.index]` Thanks :)